# Agenda going from bold to bite-sized

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does "one's agenda going from bold to bite-sized" mean?

Comment: It means your agenda (i.e. goals you expect to accomplish) went from very large to very small.

Comment: @virmaior: Looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

It means your agenda (i.e. goals you expect to accomplish) went from very large to very small.

bite-sized per google:

> (of a piece of food) small enough to be eaten in one mouthful.

and then by extension into informal usage:

> very small or short.